# How to delete an account for a now unused ftp server from finders "connect at login" list

Tags: macos, finder, ftp

EDIT2: I found the solution, see my answer below.

EDIT: The question may be a bit misleading I don't have it in the favorites bar, the problem is that finder always tries to connect to a server when I start my machine or log in.

I once saved an ftp server as a "favorite" in finder (so finder would automatically try to connect to it at startup). I no longer use this service, but finder still tries to connect to it automatically at every startup, I'm not sure how to delete this server from the list of servers finder tries to connect to automatically. How do I do that?

Some things I have tried: It has been removed from favorite servers and I also cleared the recent servers list in the "Connect to Server" menu. This had no effect.

Comment: If the server is not in the favorites bar, where is it? Could you attack an screenshot?

Comment: yeah, good idea

Answer (score 1):

Just hold the <kbd>⌘</kbd> button down, click and hold on the item you wish to remove, and drag it off the Finder’s window.

Additionally you should try Go → Connect to Server (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>). There you must see a list of your favorite servers. If your server is there, you could select it and hit Remove in the bottom of that screen.

Comment: sorry, my question was a bit misleading, I edited it

Comment: It's not in favorite servers and I also emptied recent servers in the "Connect to Server" menu without any effect. :/

Comment: Did you try to locate in under Preferences → Users & Groups → Username → Login Items?

Comment: Another posible solution is unchecking the "Share library on local network" box in itunes preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I kept googling and found a solution (with some modifications due to OS updates, see below):

[How to delete an account for a now unused ftp server from finders "connect at login" list](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164944/how-to-delete-an-account-for-a-now-unused-ftp-server-from-finders-connect-at-lo)

I did the same thing except the option is now in "System Preferences" under "Users & Groups" (select the relevant user and go to login items).

Answer (score -1):

Use the Keychain Access app under Utilities. Delete the latest FTP entry and you're done.